# R plotly: using scaleanchor and constraintoward leaves white space between plotted data and title

Tags: r, layout, axis, r-plotly

I created a kind of interactive calendar heatmap using the following code. It is quite long but should be reproducible.

```
library(plotly)
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(widgetframe)

df <- data.frame(dom = sequence(31,1,1),
             Januar= sample(50:500, 31),
             Februar = sample(50:500, 31),
             März =sample(50:500, 31),
             April = sample(50:500, 31),
             Mai = sample(50:500, 31))

df <- as.data.table(df)
df<- melt(df, id.vars= "dom",variable.name="month",value.name="value", na.rm=T)
df<- as.data.frame(df)
df <- df %>% mutate(month= factor(month,levels=as.character(c("Januar","Februar","März","April","Mai")),labels=c("Jan","Feb","Mär","Apr","Mai"),ordered=TRUE))
df$dommapped <- ordered(df$dom, levels = 31:1)
df <- df%>% mutate(group=ceiling(value/(max(value)/5)))
df$group_1<- ifelse(df$group==1,df$group,NA)
df$group_2<- ifelse(df$group==2,df$group,NA)
df$group_3<- ifelse(df$group==3,df$group,NA)
df$group_4<- ifelse(df$group==4,df$group,NA)
df$group_5<- ifelse(df$group==5,df$group,NA)

colorScale1 <- data.frame(z=c(0,1),col=c("#FFE27a","#FFE27a"))
colorScale1$col <- as.character(colorScale1$col)
colorScale2 <- data.frame(z=c(0,1),col=c("#FFCD0e","#FFCD0e"))
colorScale2$col <- as.character(colorScale2$col)
colorScale3 <- data.frame(z=c(0,1),col=c("#A1C863","#A1C863"))
colorScale3$col <- as.character(colorScale3$col)
colorScale4 <- data.frame(z=c(0,1),col=c("#76B82b","#76B82b"))
colorScale4$col <- as.character(colorScale4$col)
colorScale5 <- data.frame(z=c(0,1),col=c("#4A731c","#4A731c"))
colorScale5$col <- as.character(colorScale5$col)

f1=list(family = "Arial, sans-serif",
      size = 12,
      color = "#000000")       
f2 <- list(family = "Arial, sans-serif",
      size = 14,
      color = "#000000")

plot<-df%>%
  plot_ly(.,y = ~month, x = ~dommapped, z=~group_1, text=~value,name="group1", type="heatmap", xgap=2, ygap=2,hovertemplate=" <extra>%{y}. %{x}: Ø %{text} cases</extra>",
          hoverongaps=FALSE,colorscale=colorScale1,showlegend=TRUE, showscale=FALSE) %>%
  add_trace(.,y = ~month, x = ~dommapped, z=~group_2, text=~value,name="group2", type="heatmap", xgap=2, ygap=2,hovertemplate=" <extra>%{y}. %{x}: Ø %{text} cases</extra>",
            hoverongaps=FALSE,colorscale=colorScale2,showlegend=TRUE, showscale=FALSE) %>%
  add_trace(.,y = ~month, x = ~dommapped, z=~group_3, text=~value,name="group3", type="heatmap", xgap=2, ygap=2,hovertemplate=" <extra>%{y}. %{x}: Ø %{text} cases</extra>",
            hoverongaps=FALSE,colorscale=colorScale3,showlegend=TRUE, showscale=FALSE) %>%
  add_trace(.,y = ~month, x = ~dommapped, z=~group_4, text=~value,name="group4",type="heatmap", xgap=2, ygap=2,hovertemplate=" <extra>%{y}. %{x}: Ø %{text} cases</extra>",
            hoverongaps=FALSE,colorscale=colorScale4,showlegend=TRUE, showscale=FALSE) %>%
  add_trace(.,y = ~month, x = ~dommapped, z=~group_5, text=~value,name="group5", type="heatmap", xgap=2, ygap=2,hovertemplate=" <extra>%{y}. %{x}: Ø %{text} cases</extra>",
            hoverongaps=FALSE,colorscale=colorScale5,showlegend=TRUE, showscale=FALSE)
plot<-plot %>%
  layout(title =list(text= "Very long title about content of graph",
                     xref = "paper",
                     x = 0,
                     font = f2),
         hoverlabel=list(bgcolor="#ffffff",
                         bordercolor ="#ffffff",
                         font=f2),
         showlegend = TRUE,
         separators = ', ',
         plot_bgcolor='#ffffff',
         legend=list(itemclick="toggleothers",
                     orientation="h",
                     title=list(font=f1,
                                text="title"),
                     yanchor="top",
                     y=-0.25),
         modebar = list(color = "#a3a3a3",
                        activecolor = "#000000"),
         xaxis = list(title = "Day of month",
                      zeroline = FALSE, 
                      gridcolor = 'ffff',
                      autorange = "reversed",
                      constraintoward="left"), 
         yaxis = list(title="month",zeroline = FALSE,gridcolor = 'ffff',autorange = "reversed",
                      scaleanchor="x", constraintoward = "bottom"))

    plot<- plot %>% config(modeBarButtonsToRemove = list('autoScale2d'))
    plot<- plot %>% config(locale='de')
    plot<- plot %>% config(toImageButtonOptions = list(format = "png",filename = "",width = 760,height = 600))
    plot<- plot %>% onRender("function(el, x) {Plotly.d3.select('.cursor-crosshair').style('cursor', 'default')}")
    plot$sizingPolicy$browser$padding <- 0 
    htmlwidgets::saveWidget(title = "plot", frameableWidget(plot), "directory/plot_1.html")
```

The `scaleanchor` and `constraintoward` commands help to get the design I need. Otherwise the boxes wouldn't be square format.
But it leads - depending on the browser window size - a big [white space between graph and title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyyCq.png).
Setting the `range` for the yaxis does not work.
Setting the `margin` also didn't work so far.

I thought I have to find a solution without `scaleanchor` and `constraintoward` to get the needed aspect ratio. So I tried to change the `layout` by using `aspectratio` and `aspectmode`.

```
layout(title =list(text= "Very long title about content of graph",
                     xref = "paper",
                     x = 0,
                     font = f2),
         hoverlabel=list(bgcolor="#ffffff",
                         bordercolor ="#ffffff",
                         font=f2),
         showlegend = TRUE,
         separators = ', ',
         plot_bgcolor='#ffffff',
         legend=list(itemclick="toggleothers",
                     orientation="h",
                     title=list(font=f1,
                                text="title"),
                     yanchor="top",
                     y=-0.25),             
         modebar = list(color = "#a3a3a3",
                        activecolor = "#000000"),
         xaxis = list(title = "Day of month",
                      zeroline = FALSE, 
                      gridcolor = 'ffff',
                      autorange = "reversed"), 
         yaxis = list(title="month",zeroline = FALSE,gridcolor = 'ffff',autorange = "reversed"),
         scene=list(aspectmode="manual",
                    aspectratio=list(x=3,
                                     y=1)))
```

But this also didn't work.
I would be happy, if someone has an other idea or solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution for my problem.

By changing in `layout` for `yaxis` the key `constraintoward` to `constraintoward = "top"` and adding `constrain="domain"` I get the effect I need.
So the code for the `yaxis`-layout looks like this:

```
layout(yaxis = list(title="month",
                    zeroline = FALSE,
                    gridcolor = 'ffff',
                    autorange = "reversed",
                    scaleanchor="x",
                    constraintoward = "top",
                    constrain="domain"))
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't intentional whitespace between the plot and title. What is happening is that `plotly` has anchored the title at the top, and then it uses the available space for everything else.

If you look at it in RStudio, just adjusting the `viewer` pane will change it to the appearance you are looking for.

#### View One

[image]

#### View Two

This version uses the exact same code, just a different viewer pane size.

[image]

(I added a border so that the whitespace was more evident.)

If you're planning to save the plot, control the size when saving. If you're using R Markdown, control the size with `knitr` options.

So you are aware:

In your question, you used `colorScale` multiple times, but that object doesn't exist. I improvised.

You also used objects `f1` and `f2`, but these objects weren't provided, so I commented them out.

Lastly, I added a buffer above the title, so that it wasn't touching the top of the viewer pane using the following code:

```
  layout(margin = list(l = 50, r = 50,
                       b = 50, t = 50,
                       pad = 20))
```

To put that into perspective--the margin before I changed it:

```
  "layout": {
    "margin": {
      "b": 40,
      "l": 60,
      "t": 25,
      "r": 10
    }
```

If you'd like to explore things like these settings that you never chose, take a look at `plotly_json(plot)`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the errors in my code. I corrected the `colorScale` variable calls and added the objects `f1` and `f2` as well as added the necessary librarys.

Comment: I noticed, that the whitespace was kind of depending on the `viewer` size. The intention of this plot is, to embed it in a website with helb of an iframe (there is no other solution for this). So the viewer size might change in width. This affects the size of the plot, which the leads to the "white space". I could change the `layout` of the `yaxis` to `constraintoward = "top" `. But then I have a similar problem with the `xaxis`.

Comment: I also edited my question by adding the code I am using for saving the plot as html-file.